# Why does pdflatex write to toc-file \cyr-commands even with utf8 document encoding?

Tags: table-of-contents, cyrillic

Why does `pdflatex` (but not `lualatex`) write to toc-file `\cyr`-commands even with `utf8` document encoding instead of normal cyrillic letters? How to prevent it? I interested in solution with redefining `book.cls` commands. I redefined the  `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\unexpanded\expandafter{{#1}}}%` but it has no result.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = uk_UA
% !BIB program = bibtex8

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{misccorr}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\unexpanded\expandafter{{#1}}}%
    {\centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \Huge \sffamily\bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endpart
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Перша}

іва
\part{Друга}
іфавіфав
\end{document}
```

`Toc` looks like

```
\select@language {ukrainian}
\contentsline {part}{{\IeC {\CYRP }\IeC {\cyre }\IeC {\cyrr }\IeC {\cyrsh }\IeC {\cyra }}}{3}
\contentsline {part}{{\IeC {\CYRD }\IeC {\cyrr }\IeC {\cyru }\IeC {\cyrg }\IeC {\cyra }}}{7}
```

Comment: Note that `\unexpanded\expandafter{{#1}}` does nothing useful with the `\expandafter`, which tries to expand `{`. You can use `\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}` instead, but I'm not sure why bother: the auxiliary files are not for being human readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `\detokenize`.

For use with `hyperref`: one needs both of `\texorpdfstring` and `\phantomsection` in the patch of `\@part`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{misccorr}

% update for hyperref compatibility

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\detokenize{#1}}{#1}}%
    {\centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \Huge \sffamily\bfseries #1\par
    }%
    \@endpart
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Перша}

іва
\part{Друга}
іфавіфав
\end{document}
```

Contents of toc file:

```
\select@language {ukrainian}
\contentsline {part}{Перша}{3}
\contentsline {part}{Друга}{7}
```

and with `hyperref`:

```
\select@language {ukrainian}
\contentsline {part}{Перша}{3}{section*.2}
\contentsline {part}{Друга}{7}{section*.3}
```

Comment: thanx. But I got problem with hyperref package, the bookmarks now become unreadabl.

Comment: @sergiokapone see update.

Comment: @sergiokapone there is a problem with hyperlinks, though.

Comment: with your updates it works fine

Comment: I needed to add `\phantomsection` to your `\@part` patch, else the hyperlinks either from bookmarks of from TOC did not work with me.

Comment: Yes I have the same behaviour. May be, this is because of redefining standart book class \@part macro.

Answer (score 2):

In principle at least different parts of the document can be using different input encodings so the mechanism was designed to always write auxiliary files in the encoding neutral `LICR` ascii markup.

In practice, especially of you are using UTF-8, a single encoding is used for the whole document, but UTF-8, and UTF-8 support on LaTeX are some years younger than the design of the encoding support for toc files.

Comment: As I understand you, there is no solution due to  restrictions of pdaflatex?

Comment: @sergiokapone no, you could write out and read back in utf8 but you'd want to disable almost all of the inputenc mechanism which is designed to convert input into the markup form, which can then be used for file writing or different font encodings. So to do a proper job of it it is a bigger change than is worth doing for a toc file which is just an internal file. It is more important to be able to write utf8 when making terminal output (or pdf bookmarks) where tex macro syntax is less than ideal. But your question asked why is it that way, so I addressed the "why" not how to change it.